# Best Educational Operating System For Study?

Tags: operating-system, osdev

What's the best operating system to study in order to write your own x86 operating system from scratch?

Comment: I'm just curious... why would you want to do that?

Comment: Writing your own OS, even a very simple one, is a very good way to learn how they work.

Comment: I don't know if I can give you an answer you could understand since I don't really understand your question. I don't understand how you could not want to write an operating system. We must be from opposite sides of the galaxy.

Comment: I leant a lot from the  µC/OS book it comes with source code (Proprietary, but friendly-ish licence, as far as proprietary licences go. ) for the OS, and the book gives instruction of how to port to your choice of CPU. Plus a lot of OS theory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) was created for pretty much that exact purpose.

Have fun!

Comment: Don't forget Tannenbaum's book which has the theory and the practice and was the reason Minix was written: http://www.amazon.com/Operating-Systems-Design-Implementation-Second/dp/0136386776

Comment: Even better ulix from unlixos.org Ulix was written in C and Assembler for the Intel x86 architecture Ulix has already been used three times in operating system courses at TH Nürnberg (Nuremberg Institute of Technology)

Answer (score 9):

It might be difficult to comprehend the source for an entire OS all at once. The [tutorials](http://wiki.osdev.org/Tutorials) over at [osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/) have a few "bare bones" code samples to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote my version of x86 kernel from scratch! (for my [OS class project](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410/)) and that was experience I couldn't probably describe. You can find valuable resources at above link.

Answer (score 2):

For my OS class in college we used the [Nachos](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/tom/nachos/) OS Project and implemented that.  I did the C++ version, however I think there is also a Java port of this as well.  I remember it being very interesting and learning a great deal, even though it was a lot of work.

Comment: Nuts! I was going to say NachOS - we used it at UWaterloo for our OS class. Lemme just say - any system where kernel space is little-endian and user space is big-endian is a bit of a mindfsck.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you want your Operating System to function, if you want a microkernel you should probably study Minix 3, or if you want a monolithic kernel the current linux kernel is a good place to start from (HINT: look in arch/x86/boot, there is some very interesting code in there).
However I personally think that you should read through the Intel and AMD manuals, and then do a bit of reading on the osdev.org forums and wiki. They have plenty of code to study, and are generally helpful towards newbies.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you should probably not start with an x86 architecture, or even operating systems  but maybe something like an 8-bit starter kit, like a basic [Fox11 development kit](http://www.evbplus.com/fox11_hc11_68hc11.html). In college, I wrote my first (and only) OS in Assembly for an M68HC11 processor (the one in the kit).

If you really want to build your own OS from scratch, you've got a long road ahead of you.

Comment: I know what I'm getting into. I'm already in it. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I think best way to read many different operating system sources, definitely osdev barebone tutorials, whitepapers on OS research and documentation on your target hardware.

I personally would recommend looking at l4-ka pistachio kernel, written in pretty darn good C++. There are also multiple smaller projects definitely worth checking out, like jimix or pedigree.

Best to stick around osdev forums and wiki - there is a lot of information there already answered - see http://forum.osdev.org and http://wiki.osdev.org

Answer (score 0):

I read this article a while back. You might find it interesting. This guy wrote MINIX back in the day for the very purpose of teaching OS concepts. So it would probably be a good simple OS to study. http://www.cs.vu.nl/~ast/brown/

However, as Martin and Cory mentioned, it's a big chunk to chew.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much point in studying obsolete OS's which is pretty much all current OS's as they tend to have long lives. Have a look at some fresh ideas (although based on tried and true) like [Singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29)